# Are project included through gradle safe?

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

Let's say I want to include a project in my app using gradle. For instance,

I include

compile 'something'

in my build.gradle file

Can I be assured it's safe to include it in my project without going

through the project files?

Comment: Why do you have doubts?

Comment: Well, it's code that I'm installing.